# getting data from many-to-many relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this relationship:

Product:

```
public function cities()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cities', 'product_price_in_city', 'products_id', 'city_id')->withPivot('product_price_city');
}
```

Cities:

```
public function products()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_price_in_city', 'city_id', 'products_id')->withPivot('product_price_city');
}
```

Now if I need to get a price for a particular product in that city, how can I do that in Product or Cities Model?

Something like this:

I did this in Product model.
I know this is wrong, but how should I do something like this?

```
public function getProductRateForCity($city_id)
{
    return $this->cities()->where('city_id', $city_id)->where('product_id', $this->id);
}
```

Comment: Add a `->get()` after that and you should see some errors and go from there. `return $this->cities()->where('city_id', $city_id)->where('product_id', $this->id)->get();`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getProductRateForCity($city_id)
{
    return $this->cities()->where('product_price_in_city.city_id', $city_id)->get();
}
```

This did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it, like in  [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

```
$city = App\Cities::find($city_id);
$product = $city->products()->where('product_id', $product_id)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function getProductRateForCity($city_id)
{
    return $this->cities()->where('city_id', '=', $city_id)->where('product_id', '=', $this->id)->get();
}
```

should do it. Not tested.
I never saw ->where() with only two arguments.